How can I modify the response body programmatically in Manifest V3 chrome extensions
I need to figure out how to modify response bodies to GET requests in a v3 chrome extension.   I have now spent the better part of 4 days trying to get this to work, and nothing seems to.
I've heard about the Requestly extension, but I've been unable to figure out how to use it to programatically modify GET responses, in particular ones for javascript sources, and I'm not even sure that it has that ability, not to mention I only even want to do this modification when certain conditions for the url and path are met.  I also know how to do manual overrides using the Chrome Devtools, but I need something more flexible, and that I can programatically detect.  ModResponse is another prebuilt extension, but I can't even access the source code for that, so I'm not sure if it's even usable for my situation.
I was going to just use v2 in Manifest.json and use chrome.webRequest.filterResponseData to get a filter to modify the response, but v2 is apparently deprecated and will not apparently even be supported in future versions of chrome, according to messages that show up when I try to use it, so I'd rather avoid that.
onBeforeRequest in v3 has no access to the body, onRequestCompleted has access to the body but no means to change it, and declarativeNetRequest doesn't have access to the body either.
I even went so far as to try to write my own custom proxy in python that would make the necessary changes to response bodies that I want (as long as the top level domain and path that it's trying to get meet certain parameters, otherwise I just want it to act as though the proxy isn't even there.
While I understand that there are free proxies out there, I need very specific functionality in that I want to programatically alter the responses that the web browser sees when it makes certain requests.   This is outside of the domain of a general proxy server, and requires a custom approach.
But trying to write my own proxy proved to be incredibly complicated, and I couldn't even get the thing to work with most web pages, and the logistics of supporting https are well outside of my domain.
All I want is the ability to programatically alter the response body based on the url and the file being requested.  The mechanism needs to be able to have access to the computer's filesystem for reading certain files based on the request, so I can't put any of my logic in content.js
I'm well aware that similar questions  have been asked here before, but the answers don't seem applicable to what I'm trying to do, often suggesting the very things I've already tried.
EDIT:
Okay, I literally say in my comments WHY the recommended solutions about using existing chrome plugins that I've been finding in stackoverflow aren't adequate, and this question gets flagged as a duplicates with those as answers.   What gives?

In Requestly you can modify response of a GET request, tried it on agoda website. Here is a helpful blog post for the same.
P.S. I am one of the maintainers of Requestly.

Requestly is a non-trivial extension, and it is not at all obvious how I could start with it and end up with what just what I want.... a static set of rules that PROGRAMATICALLY determin  to filter, and then a javascript function that actually modfies the body of the text, based on the url, and the filename requested, in       Requestly does not do that.  My use case requires that the code be in the service worker of the extension, because it requires filesystem access.  chrome.storage isn't good enough because of its limited size, I would need storage of a about a gigabyte or more.

Oh, and I even explicitly acknowlege it in my original draft of the question, and try to give an explanation for why it's unsuiable for my use case.
